# What is the Computer name that appears on new Macbooks ?

Tags: macbook-pro, user-account, macos

I'm selling my Macbook online and I want to reset the name of the computer to the generic name as if it's completely new from the apple store. In system preferences > sharing > Computer name. I forgot what the generic name is when you first buy the computer.

Is it "new computer" or "Generic" or "New User"? I know it's completely 100% unnecessary but I want to do it as a nice touch for the next user.

Answer (score 4):

If you have time, you could reinstall OS X and quit the installer (and shutdown the system) at the point when it asks you to enter a username and password to create your first account.

When the buyer powers it on, it will then display the OS X welcome message and allow the buyer to complete the setup as if it were bought new.

Answer (score 1):

The name is set when the first user is created. So it's directly XYZ's Macbook.

If you want a simple name, just call it Macbook.